# Stop Android from sending Notification after un-registering an application?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a weird issue with Google Notification server. When I install/register an application, I get a device id from Google, which I will use to send notifications from server. From the server I'm sending notifications to all the registered devices. The problem is that whenever a device unregisters the app and registers again, the device is getting 2 notifications. This happens because now I have 2 different device ids. I got the first when I first installed the app and the second when I unregistered and registered the app again.

Comment: If you can create a sample project and procedure for reproducing this, file a bug report on http://b.android.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send a notification with the old device token, the response should include the canonical registration Id, which tells you you should remove the old registration id from your database.
In addition, when the application unregisters, it should send an un-registration message to your server, and the server should remove the registration id from the database. You should only rely on the canonical registration Id if the user uninstalled the App (in which case your server can't be notified) and then installed it again.
One last thing - if you attempt to send the notification to the old registration Id after the user unregistered and before registering again, you should get an error message from Google that indicates the regostration Id is no longer registered (I don't remember if you'll get that error the first time you send a notification after the un-registration or only from second time).

Comment: The problem is that the Google continuously sending notification with old device id without prompting the server which is bed I think. BTW, it's good idea that I should remove the device id when user unregistered.

Comment: Don't you get a canonical registration id in the reply from Google when you send a notification with the old id?

Comment: I am not sure but Google continuosly sending notification

Comment: You should check the reply your server gets from Google each time you send a notification, and see if it contains a canonical registration id.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am getting both old and new id. Thanks. But it still weird that Google send the notfication of old device ids

Comment: Well, the fact that Google accepts the old id and delivers the message allows you to overcome situations in which your server didn't get the new id from the device. The canonical registration id returned in this case tells you to stop using the old id and start using the new one. According to the GCM documentation, eventually the old id will stop working, but I'm not sure how long that takes.